# specify a subset of all interactions for lasso with hierarchical interactions

Tags: interaction, lasso

I would like to fit a lasso model with hierarchical interactions, but only on a subset of all possible interactions. The `hierNet` package in R allows the user to provide a custom interaction matrix via the `zz` parameter, but when I create the interaction matrix with a subset of all interactions (e.g., only X1:X2 and X3:X4 among X1, X2, X3, X4) I receive the following error, suggesting that the program is expecting the full set of interactions.

```
Error: length(zz) == n * (choose(p, 2) + p) is not TRUE
```

Do libraries exist that allow the user to specify the interaction terms? For example, `glmnetUtils` provides a formula interface for `glmnet` models. Ideally I would supply a formula to hierNet that specifies the interactions of interest.

Comment: try https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glinternet/index.html which uses a latent overlapping group lasso penalty instead of a group lasso penalty. It could be that the method it was programmed in such a way to do what you want

Comment: right, so this is a nice package, and is what I used to obtain the result above. I believe `hierNet` considers all interactions (the full lower diagonal), but I want to specify a custom set.

Comment: I just linked a different one. The first one was linked by mistake!

Comment: haha... yup, tried that one too :(

Comment: they both only admit all interactions?

Comment: it has a `interactionCandidates` argument, but it, "... consider[s] interactions between interactionCandidates and all other variables." seems unable to isolate specific pairs of variables.

Comment: Interesting! I'll try to get back to you with something.